# Access local host in PHP (sublime text 3)

Tags: php, twitter, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I am currently writing a program using the Twitter API. I would like to know how to access my local host to 'run' the system. I am using Sublime Text 3, but can downgrade if needs be.

I am following a YouTube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPnGB7a7dO0. He simply types in local host and it works.

I am fairly new to this, so please excuse me if I am saying something incredibly stupid.

Comment: What's the correlation between "How to access localhost" and Sublime Text ? Are you sure that you have the correct environment (eg: Apache is installed)

Comment: I am using Sublime Text to code. I have seen tutorials on youtube using this program and they can access localhost.

Comment: @liamsheridann Sublime is just an editor where you can write your code. You need a local webserver so you can access `localhost` and run your PHP code

Comment: @KhorneHoly is there a tutorial that you could link in which I could follow this?

Comment: Hmmm well... I guess you should see how to install PHP to run it locally. If you are on windows you can install `Xampp` or something like this (which contains PHP, Apache, Mysql). Edit: Btw, Sublime Text is good enough for coding.

Comment: to connect to localhost just go to `127.0.0.1`on your browser. but you will not nothing there unless you have a server running on your machine or computer. try `WAMP(windows)`,`XAMMP` just search for and you can find many